# Format a date that following format M/D/YYYY

Tags: excel, vba

I got the following format for the date `1/1/2022` (MM/DD/YYYY) and I need to transform it into `01.01.2022` (DD.MM.YYYY)

I'm doing this transformation inside an array()

```
For iDateArrayRow = 1 To UBound(iDateArray, 1)
    iDateArray(iDateArrayRow, 1) = Split(iDateArray(iDateArrayRow, 1), "/")
    If iDateArray(iDateArrayRow, 1)(0) < 10 Then
        iDateArray(iDateArrayRow, 1)(0) = "0" & iDateArray(iDateArrayRow, 1)(0)
    Else
        iDateArray(iDateArrayRow, 1)(0) = iDateArray(iDateArrayRow, 1)(0)
    End If

           
    If iDateArray(iDateArrayRow, 1)(1) < 10 Then
        iDateArray(iDateArrayRow, 1)(1) = "0" & iDateArray(iDateArrayRow, 1)(1)
    Else
        iDateArray(iDateArrayRow, 1)(1) = iDateArray(iDateArrayRow, 1)(1)
    End If

    iDateArray(iDateArrayRow, 1) =
Next iDateArrayRow
```

Comment: Can you share some code and/or sample data?

Comment: Dates have no format, only the representation of a date. Do you really have dates or do you have strings (that look like a date)? And after "transformation", do you want to have dates or other string (that look like a date, but differently).

Comment: i just share it.

Comment: @nonUser See what FunThomas said. Do you have real numeric dates or are those texts that look like dates? What is the source of those dates? Where do they come from? Can you show some screenshots maybe?

Comment: the source has the date format ((but I'm not sure that it will always date, can be even text like date) and is M/D/YYYY , while the output should be text-like date in the following format DD.MM.YYYY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to deal with strings (that look like a date), use the following function. Note that there are no dates involved, only strings.

```
Function ConvertMe1(d As String) As String
    Dim tokens() As String
    tokens = Split(d, "/")
    If UBound(tokens) <> 2 Then
        ConvertMe = d
    Else
        ConvertMe = tokens(1) & "." & tokens(0) & "." & tokens(2)
    End If
End Function
```

If you want to convert your string into a *Date*:

```
Function ConvertMe2(d As String) As Date
    Dim tokens() As String
    tokens = Split(d, "/")
    If UBound(tokens) <> 2 Then Exit Function
    
    ConvertMe2 = DateSerial(Val(tokens(2)), Val(tokens(1)), Val(tokens(0)))
End Function
```

Note that a Date is a *Number* (Double). A Date can be formatted in many different ways in Excel (without changing it's value). A string cannot be formatted in Excel.